# Error - Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift3, data-conversion

I'm doing an introductory iOS developer's course, and am doing a cat-years calculator as an exercise. The following code returns the error:
`Int(AgeInCatYears.text!) = CatsROld!`

> Error - Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

In case it's important, the var CatsROld was set equal to `Int(humanYears.text!)! * 7` one line earlier.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting value to the `Label` or `textField` then you need to simply set value `(as String)` to its property `text`, but you are try to convert the value to `Int` and then you assigning value of `CatsROld` to it, that is the reason you are getting this error. So simply write like `AgeInCatYears.text = "\(CatsROld!)"`

```
AgeInCatYears.text = "\(CatsROld!)"
```

**Note:** You are force wrapping `CatsROld` value with `!`, if you are 100% sure that it will not `nil` then its ok other wise you need to use `if let` or `guard` for optional wrapping.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem!

Comment: @EnochWiley Welcome mate :)

Comment: I think I just did. Sorry for not doing that sooner!